# Seg Fault Core Dumped

Tags: c

Estou tendo esse erro no código e não consigo achar o problema, alguém pode me apontar o que estou fazendo de errado?
O que o código faz:
Recebo linha e coluna da matriz A, depois da matriz B, verifico se podem ser multiplicadas. Recebo os valores da matriz A e depois da matriz B. Nesse momento ocorre o erro. Depois disso deveria ser feita a multiplicação das matrizes e imprimir a matriz resultante.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, k, lA, cA, lB, cB;
    float **A=NULL, **B=NULL, **MULT=NULL;
    printf("\nInsira a dimensão da matriz A:");
    scanf("%d%d", &lA, &cA);
    A = (float**) malloc (lA * sizeof(float*));
    if(A == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    printf("\nInsira a dimensão da matriz B:");
    scanf("%d%d", &lB, &cB);
    if (lA != cB)
    {
        printf("\nImpossivel fazer a operação!!!");
        return 0;
    }else
        B = (float **) malloc (lB * sizeof(float*));
        if(B == NULL)
            exit(-1);
        printf("\nInsira a matriz A: ");

        for(i=0; i<lA; i++)
        {
            A[i] = (float *) malloc(cA * sizeof(float));
            if(A[i]==NULL)
                exit(-1);
            for(j=0; j<cA; j++)
                scanf("%f", &A[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n\nInsira a matriz B: ");

        for(i=0; i<lB; i++)
        {
            B[i] = (float *) malloc(cB * sizeof(float));
            if(B[i]==NULL)
                exit(-1);
            for(j=0; j<cB; j++)
                scanf("%f", &B[i][j]);
        }

        MULT = (float**)malloc(lA*sizeof(float*));
        if(MULT==NULL)
            exit(-1);
        for(i=0; i<lA; i++)
        {
            MULT[i]=(float*)malloc(cB*sizeof(float));
            if(MULT[i]==NULL)
                exit(-1);
        }

        printf("\nMatriz produto: ");

        for(i=0; i <lA; i++)
        {
            printf("\n[");
            for(j=0; j<cB; j++)
            {
                for(k=0; k<lA; k++)
                    MULT[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                printf(" %.1f", MULT[i][j]);
            }
            printf("]");
        }
        for(i=0; i<lA; i++)
            free(A[i]);
        free(A);
        for(i=0; i<lB; i++)
            free(B[i]);
        free(B);
        for(i=0; i<lA; i++)
            free(MULT[i]);
        free(MULT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: rodei na minha máquina duas matrizes de ordem 2 e funcionou de boa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que você se enrolou: lá na linha 15, você diz:

```
if (lA != cB)
{
    printf("\nImpossivel fazer a operação!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

Mas, para multiplicar matrizes, a quantidade de **colunas** da primeira matriz tem que bater com a quantidade de **linhas** da segunda. Esse entendimento é reforçado pela linha 63, em que a multiplicação procede:

```
MULT[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
```

Note como o índice `k` está percorrendo as colunas de A e as linhas de B.

Portanto, as alterações que precisam ser feitas são na linha 15, dizendo `if (cA != lB)` em vez de `if (lA != cB)` e na linha 62 (a causa do segfault), em que `for(k=0; k<cB; k++)` tem que ser substituído por `for(k=0; k<lB; k++)`

Com essas duas substituições o código passa a funcionar para matrizes não-quadradas; para matrizes quadradas, ele já funciona como está (por coincidência).